# JavaScript and getting the value of radio button

Tags: javascript, html, output

I tried to create an online calculation form using javascript, everything is ok except radio buttons.

Scenario:

```
x(select list) =
   item1 - value="11.2"
   item2 - value="7.6"
   item3 - value="7"

y=(input number)

z=(input number)

coverkind=(radio button)
   if 1 selected >> coverkind = z*800
   if 2 selected >> coverkind = ((y/16)+1)*8*z

totalprice= (x*y*z)+(1000*z)+coverkind
```

my work till now:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function getselectionPrice() {
     var elt = document.getElementById("selectionone");
     var selectionPrice = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;
     var y = document.getElementById("y").value;
     var z = document.getElementById("z").value;
     var ser = (selectionPrice * y * z);
     var dz = z*1000;

     var coverkind = document.getElementById("cover").value;
     if (coverkind == 'soft') {
         var SizePrice = (z * 800);
     } else {
         var SizePrice = ((y / 16) + 1) * 8 * z;
     }

     var finalPrice =  ser + dz;
     document.getElementById("totalPrice").value = finalPrice;
 }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

        <form action="" id="calcform" onsubmit="return false;">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <fieldset>
                        <label>select</label>
                        <select id="selectionone" name='selectionone' onChange="getselectionPrice()">
                            <option value="11.2">1</option>
                            <option value="7.6">2</option>
                            <option value="7">3</option>
                        </select>
                        <br/>
                        <p>y
                            <input type="text" id="y" onchange="getselectionPrice()" />
                        </p>
                        <p>z
                            <input type="text" id="z" onchange="getselectionPrice()" />
                        </p>
                        <label>cover</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="cover" value="hard" />hard
                        <br />
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="cover" value="soft" />soft
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br/>The new calculated price:
                        <INPUT type="text" id="totalPrice" Size=8>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <input type='submit' id='submit' value='Submit' onclick="getselectionPrice()" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

If I remove the coverkind from js, the rest works fine. I googled about getting value from radio button and nothing found very relevant to this situation. 
firebug error panel :

TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
var coverkind = document.getElementById("cover").value;

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. Considering editing your question to make it (a lot) clearer.

Comment: thanks for your advise,
its a form with one option field , two input number and one radio button, then calculates the values through the formula and shows the final number.

Comment: @LD - I have posted solution of your problem. Check it and let me know the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution of your problem.

First give a same id to your radio buttons.
The checked property will tell you whether the element is selected:

```
<input type="radio" id="cover" name="cover" value="hard" checked="checked" />hard
<br />
<br>
<input type="radio" id="cover" name="cover" value="soft" />soft
```

and in JavaScript function, you can get it.

```
var coverkind = null;
    if (document.getElementById('cover').checked)
   {
    coverkind = document.getElementById('cover').value;
   }
   if (coverkind == 'soft') {
         var SizePrice = (z * 800);
   } else {
         var SizePrice = ((y / 16) + 1) * 8 * z;
   }
```

Comment: Thank you; your code cleared the error but it still doesn't consider values of radio buttons in calculation.

Comment: coverkind variable will get value "hard" or "soft". Based on coverkind valaue condition will be true or false and if or else code will be executed. SizePrice will get result of your calculation. Note - SizePrice is local variable, you can't use outside. Now just check you calculation logic. Except calculation everything in working fine. Use development tools to find out the mistake. There is no mistake in my logic. I have tested it again.

Comment: Still wrestling with it :D.
I also tried to change the radio buttons into option list , but same thing happened.

Comment: I don't know what you are doing. There may be a minor mistake. Simple is that,   first radio button is default checked, if you doesn't select second radio button, then coverkind variable value will be hard and and if we select second radio button coverkind variable value will be soft. Create a fiddle, so that i can solve it out easily.

Comment: I have fixed your issue. You are not following my condition as i written in my posted answer. Please check this fiddler now and let me know. http://jsfiddle.net/PuneetChawla/us8e6qma/1/

Comment: I hope, now your problem has been solved. If not then tell me.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jQuery, you can get the value of the checked radio button in one line.

```
var Val = $("input[name=cover]:checked").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the output tag if you want or something else for your output. (a `<p>` element for example). Just make sure you give anything you want to access in your Javascipt an 'id' value.

You'll need to create a new file and call it something like 'script.js'. Google how to include this script in your html document.

Some of the things you'll need to use in your script:

> `document.getElementById(str)`    *Returns an object representing an html
>   element with an id of 'str'*
>
> `parseFloat(str)` *Takes a string 'str' and return the float value*
>
> `.value`  *This is a read/write property of an input text box object
>   that contains the text value*
>
> `.checked`    *..and a property of an input radio button object.*

When you hit a wall refer to the great google ;) Put all that together and you should be on the right track.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i did as you said but it still doesn't work. could you please check it ?

Comment: Hit F12 to open the developer console. Click on console. Look for errors `When you hit a wall refer to the great google` Also the term 'doesn't work' is a software developers worst enemy :) What IS happening and what is NOT happening?